# limit of function with one fractional term

Tags: calculus, limits

There is one question on my assignment this week that I just dont understand how to get to a solution for...I'm pretty sure you have to use l'hopitals rule, but i don't know how to get the function into one, differentiable fraction..can someone help?

I've tried splitting into 2 functions,and finding the limit of each, but that doesnt help solve it.

$$\lim_{x->0}\left( \frac 1{x^2} - \cot^2x\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

write $f(x)$ as

$$f(x)=\frac{\sin^2(x)-x^2\cos^2(x)}{x^4}\frac{x^2}{\sin^2(x)}$$

$$=\frac{\sin(x)+x\cos(x)}{x}\frac{\sin(x)-x\cos(x)}{x^3}\frac{x^2}{\sin^2(x)}$$

and use l'Hopital's rule to left fractions.

the extreme right one goes to$1$.

For the first fraction

$$\frac{2\cos(x)-x\sin(x)}{1}\to 2$$
For the second, you will need l'Hopital three times to get $\frac{1}{3}$.

the final result is $\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: thanks! but i dont see how using l'hopitals on the first 2 fractions help, don't they still go to 0? @abdallah hammam

Comment: When you "plug in zero in those two left fractions, you still get "zero over zero", (please check!) thus indeterminate and the Rule can be applied. And this is what he has done...

Comment: @imranfat Use l'Hopital in each fraction.